# Can Domain-based attributes span across models

Tags: master-data-services

If models in Master Data Services are representations of subject areas (such as customer, product, etc.), is it possible to have a domain-based attribute that uses a different model as it's source?

For example, if creating a customer model and defining an entity called Customers, this entity will have address information for the customer.  City, State/Province, Country, etc.

But rather than creating an entity for CustomerCountry, can I use a Geography model that contains a Country entity and link to that?  Then I can also use the Geography.Country entity for Vendors and Employees.

Comment: A Master Data Services Model is more akin to a database than a subject area. An entity is like a table in that database. And an attribute is like a column. I've yet to see anywhere in the documentation that allows objects in a Model to reference anything other than other objects in the same model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot cross model boundaries - the primary reason is that a model is the unit of versioning. There are two workarounds:

1. Duplicate the entities in question - i.e. copy the geography entities into your customer model
2. Reference an entity by code - i.e. add a CITY_CODE to your customer entity

Neither of these are great options 1) is unwieldy and 2) doesn't maintain automatic integrity.

Personally I use option 2) where I can with some additional logic/business rules outside of MDS to ensure that codes match. This is easier with codes that are global and do not change such as country and city codes.

Comment: I chose neither because it is Master Data after-all. I see no need to partition a model at all unless you have application domains that are entirely orthogonal - hence overlapping entities would be a code smell. Partitioning of dimensions might make sense but that is done with ETL in the DW and not in Master Data. Please let me know if my reasoning is faulty - I'm not afraid to admit, I'm making this up as I go.

Comment: I must admit that you reasoning @ScottLHolmes seems right.
Unfortunately I have inherited a rather fragmented MDS with many models. We could call it error by design, but basically my options is.
Either to remake and consolidate all their models, or go with it, and try to make the best, and the logic behind to keep the same entities in sync across models.
The reason for this fragmentation was that the client had the idea that different people should maintain different models, which seems legit, but unfortuneatly makes some entities abundant ;)

Comment: If you are using MDS 2016 then this problem goes away due to a new feature "Entity Sync" : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt244806.aspx

Comment: @ScottLHolmes the reason why you might have multiple models is from a manageability point of view - assume that your marketing department is responsible for keeping the Product model up to date but the sales department is responsible for your Customer model. They might have different schedules, authorization and business processes. Having both in the same model would complicate matters somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

This seems quite old but this is now possible in 2016 and is accomplished though Entity Synch.  The idea is you can synch your entity across models.  There are two ways to run the synch, either on demand or automatically.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/master-data-services/entity-sync-relationship-master-data-services for more details